# Make textview marquee if text string is smaller than screen size

Tags: android, xml, textview, marquee

When textview text is "small" then textview doesn't scroll but when textview text is "large with text exceeding screen size" then it scroll.
I also wan't my text to marquee even when is it "small"

XML text view :

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tickler_message"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.MarqueeTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="@string/placeholder_marquee_text"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

Activity :

```
binding.ticklerMessage.text = ticklerPlainText
binding.ticklerMessage.isSelected = true
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to check width of textview with text,

```
If it exceed screen width -> textview marquee text properties, 
else -> animate textview from left to right.
```

Create animation **tickler_translation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fillEnabled = "true"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Textview

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tickler_message"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.MarqueeTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="@string/placeholder_marquee_text"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

In Activity

```
if (textCanScroll(ticklerMessage, ticklerPlainText)) {
    //Show Marquee text if text length is greater than screen width
    ticklerMessage.text = ticklerPlainText
    ticklerMessage.maxLength(ticklerPlainText.length)
    ticklerMessage.isSelected = true
    ticklerMessage.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    ticklerLayout.makeVisible()
} else {
    //Animate text horizontally if length is lesser than screen width
    val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(it, R.anim.tickler_translation)
    ticklerMessage.startAnimation(animation)
    ticklerMessage.text = ticklerPlainText
    ticklerMessage.gravity = Gravity.START or Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
    ticklerLayout.makeVisible()
}

private fun textCanScroll(textView: TextView, text: String): Boolean {
        try {
            val bounds = Rect()
            val textPaint: Paint = textView.paint
            textPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, bounds)
            val height: Int = bounds.height()
            val width: Int = bounds.width()
            if (activity != null) {
                val screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
                return width >= screenWidth
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            return false
        }
        return false
    }
```